# Reading an array of unicode numbers as unicode string (in javascript)

Tags: javascript, unicode

Letter `ł` (l with tail) is represented in Unicode as U+0142, hex: xc5 x82, decimal: 197 130.

I have an array in JavaScript:

```
var b = [197, 130];
```

How to make string `ł` from it?

I tried [this](http://jsfiddle.net/w9zEA/) on JSFiddle:

```
var s;
s = String.fromCharCode(b[0], b[1]);
```

But then `s` is equal to `Å` (A with something on top). 
I also tried other methods in the fiddle, but I can't get the correct result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For two byte sequences you need to use mask [`110xxxxx 10xxxxxx`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description), which refers to:

```
var bytes = [0xc5, 0x82];  // [197, 130]

String.fromCharCode(((bytes[0] & 0x1f) << 6) | (bytes[1] & 0x3f));  // "ł"
```

Answer (score 1):

> hex: xc5 x82

That's the UTF-8 byte encoding of `ł`.

> s = String.fromCharCode(b[0], b[1]);

That's interpreting each byte as a single character, which is effectively decoding the bytes using the ISO-8859-1 encoding, because this encoding happens to share the same numbers as the first 256 characters of Unicode.

There is a neat JavaScript trick to turn a string where each character stands in for the byte of the same number, into a UTF-8 decoded string: send it through the legacy `escape()` builtin function, which is a broken URL-encoder, and then decode it using the real URL-decoder, `decodeURIComponent`.

So for any Array of UTF-8 bytes you can get the decoded Unicode String by doing:

```
function utf8BytesToString(b) {
    return decodeURIComponent(escape(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, b)));
}

utf8BytesToString([0xc5, 0x82]) // "ł"
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably after `String.fromCodePoint`:

```
String.fromCodePoint(128105, 8205, 128188) // ‍

// or if you have the hex values, parse them first:
String.fromCodePoint(parseInt("1F469", 16), parseInt("200D", 16), parseInt("1F4BC", 16)) // ‍

// for arbitrary numbers of points, use JS spread notation:
let codePoints = [128105, 8205, 128188];
String.fromCodePoint(...codePoints)
```